# Airplane seat reservation using c#

Tags: c#

I stumbled across a source-code for a seat reservation system online (using a console) in c++. The program allows one to select first class, business class and economy class on an airplane, select row and finally a seat. I have been trying to rewrite the same code but in c# but encountered errors, below is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] airplane = new int[13, 6];
        sbyte[,] airchar = new sbyte[13, 6];
        string ticket;
        int[] row = new int[2];
```

**//            sbyte seat;**

```
        //--------------------------------------------
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                airchar[i, j] = (sbyte)'*';
                airplane[i, j] = 0;

            }
        }
        //--------------------------------------------
        for (;;)
        {
            Console.Write("Rows 1 and 2 are first class (FC)");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("Rows 3 through 7 are business class (BC)");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("Rows 8 through 13 are economy class (EC)");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("* - Available");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("X - Occupied");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("     \tA\tB\tC\tD\tE\tF");
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("Row 1\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[0, 0]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[0, 1]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[0, 2]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[0, 3]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[0, 4]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[0, 5]);
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("Row 2\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[1, 0]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[1, 1]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[1, 2]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[1, 3]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[1, 4]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[1, 5]);
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("Row 3\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[2, 0]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[2, 1]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[2, 2]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[2, 3]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[2, 4]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[2, 5]);
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("Row 4\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[3, 0]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[3, 1]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[3, 2]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[3, 3]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[3, 4]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[3, 5]);
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("Row 5\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[4, 0]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[4, 1]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[4, 2]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[4, 3]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[4, 4]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[4, 5]);
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("Row 6\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[5, 0]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[5, 1]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[5, 2]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[5, 3]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[5, 4]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[5, 5]);
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("Row 7\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[6, 0]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[6, 1]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[6, 2]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[6, 3]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[6, 4]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[6, 5]);
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("Row 8\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[7, 0]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[7, 1]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[7, 2]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[7, 3]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[7, 4]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[7, 5]);
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("Row 9\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[8, 0]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[8, 1]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[8, 2]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[8, 3]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[8, 4]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[8, 5]);
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("Row 10\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[9, 0]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[9, 1]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[9, 2]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[9, 3]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[9, 4]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[9, 5]);
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("Row 11\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[10, 0]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[10, 1]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[10, 2]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[10, 3]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[10, 4]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[10, 5]);
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("Row 12\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[11, 0]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[11, 1]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[11, 2]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[11, 3]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[11, 4]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[11, 5]);
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.Write("Row 13\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[12, 0]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[12, 1]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[12, 2]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[12, 3]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[12, 4]);
            Console.Write("\t");
            Console.Write(airchar[12, 5]);
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.Write("\n");
```

**// Problem starts here**

```
            Console.Write("Enter Ticket type (FC, BC, or EC): ");
            ticket = ConsoleInput.ReadToWhiteSpace(true);
            Console.Write("Desired Row: ");
            row[0] = ConsoleInput.ReadToWhiteSpace(true);
            Console.Write("Desired seat (A,B,C,D,E or F): ");
            seat = ConsoleInput.ReadToWhiteSpace(true);


            switch (seat)
            {
                case 'A':
                case 'a':
                    row[0] = row[0] - 1;
                    row[1] = 1;
                    row[1] = row[1] - 1;
                    break;

                case 'B':
                case 'b':
                    row[0] = row[0] - 1;
                    row[1] = 2;
                    row[1] = row[1] - 1;
                    break;

                case 'C':
                case 'c':
                    row[0] = row[0] - 1;
                    row[1] = 3;
                    row[1] = row[1] - 1;
                    break;

                case 'D':
                case 'd':
                    row[0] = row[0] - 1;
                    row[1] = 4;
                    row[1] = row[1] - 1;
                    break;

                case 'E':
                case 'e':
                    row[0] = row[0] - 1;
                    row[1] = 5;
                    row[1] = row[1] - 1;
                    break;

                case 'F':
                case 'f':
                    row[0] = row[0] - 1;
                    row[1] = 6;
                    row[1] = row[1] - 1;
                    break;

            }
```

The syntax error appears in **ConsoleInput.ReadToWhiteSpace(true);** for ticket, row[0] and seat. Also another error that occurred is in the switch statement where all cases are highlighted and states "**Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'sbyte'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**"

I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using `Console.ReadLine()` instead? Also, this isn't related to your problem but if you use `switch (seat.ToUpper())` it will save you having a case for the lowercase of each letter.

Comment: in switch you have seat which is sbyte and in case you case chars

Comment: Can you update your question, mentioning location of char to sbyte error?

Comment: Actually, instead of `Console.ReadLine()` you would probably want `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar` instead. My bad there.

Comment: Debugging help questions require a [mcve] as per the [help]. Your code is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to make sure that your code is Minimal (only the code necessary to reproduce your issue in your question), Complete (users do not need anything else to reproduce your issue), and Verifiable (the provided code does reproduce the exact issue you are facing). As it is your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Note that this is also a common [downvote reason](http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In switch you have seat which is sbyte and in case you case chars. so either convert each char in case to `sbyte` or `return` `char` from method `ReadToWhiteSpace`.

Better you can use `Console.ReadLine()` or `Console.Read()`(gives ASCII value) instead of `ConsoleInput.ReadToWhiteSpace` to get input from console.

Comment: then? something went wrong ?

Comment: you try row[0] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());...because As I mentioned Console.Read will give you ASCII value, so you will have to compare with ascii value later in your code

Comment: its giving the correct value. you can check it by Doing Console.WriteLine(seat);. for your information 42 and 88 are ascii values for * and X respectively.

Comment: Downvoter please give reason